# Running sever but throwing an "Exception has occured" eccured. Django python

Tags: python, django, graphql

[this server breaks when I enter my login details and this is where the system breaks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mvrQ.png)

Comment: From [MCVE]: "DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then format it as code. This helps others more easily read and test your code."

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As stated in the previous comment please don't use images of code / errors. To better understand how to use Stack Overflow, please take the [tour], visit the [help] and have a look at [ask].